# How do I add a literal newline character while using sed's string replace?

Tags: regex, bash, replace, sed, newline

Let me explain the scenario I am facing: I have a perl file that, among other things, creates a 'header' string used by another process. This is defined in the perl script (script.pl) as:

```
$str = "START\n" .
"PARAM1=blah\n" .
"PARAM2=blah2\n" .
"PARAM3=blah3\n";
```

etc

I need to modify the value of $str by appending more values from a bash script, so I thought I would use sed. This is what I have so far:

```
str_new="\"NEWPARAM1=blah\" .\n\"NEWPARAM2=blah2\" .\n";
sed -i "/START/{n;s/^/$str_new/}" script.pl
```

This sort of works, what I'm getting is:

```
$str = "START\n" .
       "NEWPARAM1=blah" .
       "NEWPARAM2=blah2" .
       "PARAM1=blah\n" .
       "PARAM2=blah2\n" .
       "PARAM3=blah3\n";
```

However, what I need is the literal '\n' to appear as well after the new parameters I've added:

```
$str = "START\n" .
       "NEWPARAM1=blah\n" .
       "NEWPARAM2=blah2\n" .
       "PARAM1=blah\n" .
       "PARAM2=blah2\n" .
       "PARAM3=blah3\n";
```

I've tried using '\n', \n in the sed replace clause but no luck. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What language is this? This is not `sh` or `bash`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I'm using this inside a bash script

Comment: Yes, what I get then is 
    $str = "START\n" .
           "NEWPARAM1=blah
           " .
           "NEWPARAM2=blah2
           " . 
etc. Incase the formatting is messed up, what it does is interpret the \\n as another newline character so it adds a newline after blah, and then another newline after the '.'

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just do the whole thing in Perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
str_new='"NEWPARAM1=blah\\n" .\n"NEWPARAM2=blah2\\n" .\n'
sed -i.bak "/START/{n;s/^/$str_new/;}" script.pl

cat script.pl
$str = "START\n" .
"NEWPARAM1=blah\n" .
"NEWPARAM2=blah2\n" .
"PARAM1=blah\n" .
"PARAM2=blah2\n" .
"PARAM3=blah3\n";
```

Comment: just be carefful with the use of $, \1 -> \9 and & in your str_new because there are the few RegEx vlaue used in replacement part of a s//

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I don't think it will be an issue for me as there is a predefined set of data from which these parameters will be populated, so I can test every case

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a heredoc in the perl to simplify the problem:

```
$str = <<EOT;
START
PARAM1=blah
PARAM2=blah2
PARAM3=blah3
EOT
```